# ActiveRecord: Reference attribute from associated model in where statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got two models with a has_many / has_many relationship. I have a variable `exp_ids` which is an array of integers representing the id's of some `ExperienceLevel` records. I need to write a query that will select all `JobDescription`s that have an `ExperienceLevel` with one of those ids.

The query must work on an existing ActiveRelation object called `job_descriptions`, which is being passed through some flow controls in my controller to filter the results based on my params.

I've tried these queries below and some other variations, but with little success. As far as I can tell, ActiveRecord thinks that `experience_levels` is an attribute, which is causing it to fail.

- `job_descriptions.where(experience_levels: exp_ids)`
- `job_descriptions.joins(:experience_levels).where(experience_levels.id: exp_ids)`
- `job_descriptions.joins(:experience_levels).where(experience_levels: exp_ids)`
- `job_descriptions.joins(:experience_levels).where("experience_levels.id IN exp_ids")`
- `job_descriptions.includes(:experience_levels).where("experience_levels.id = ?", exp_ids).references(:experience_levels)`

Here are my models:

```
class JobDescription < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :job_description_experience_levels
    has_many :experience_levels, through: :job_description_experience_levels
end

class JobDescriptionExperienceLevel < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :job_description
    belongs_to :experience_level
end

class ExperienceLevel < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :job_description_experience_levels
    has_many :job_descriptions, through: :job_description_experience_levels
end
```

I'm not sure if what I want to do is even possible. I've used a similar approach for another `job_description` filter where I selected the `company_id`, but in the case, `company_id` was an attribute of `JobDescription`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
job_descriptions.joins(:job_description_experience_levels).where(job_description_experience_levels: { experience_level_id: exp_ids })
```

Answer (score 1):

job_descriptions.joins(:experience_levels).where(experience_levels: {id: exp_ids})

Comment: This one works perfectly as well. I marked vegetaras's response as the answer because it was first, but I like yours better because it's more succinct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Note the lack of plural on the experience level.id

```
job_descriptions.includes(:experience_levels).where("experience_level.id = ?", exp_ids).references(:experience_levels)
```

Comment: I tried this one before with pluralization on `experience_levels.id` and without. Neither one worked.